# Infinite list and formula for pagination

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, math

I have some infinite pagination done in react-native. 
Each time when the user reaches out the end of the page the new data starts fetching from a server.

There are some params that should be sent with the request to get the correct data.

```
const data = { limit, offset };
```

`limit` variable determines how many items need to load.
`offset` says from which point in the database need to query them

So simply talking that's how it should look like for the pages

Page 1:

```
const limit = 10; // get 10 items 
const offset = 0; // start point
```

Page 2:

```
const limit = 20; // get 20 items 
const offset = 10;
```

Page 3:

```
const limit = 30; // get 30 items 
const offset = 30;
```

Page 4:

```
const limit = 40; // get 40 items 
const offset = 60;
```

Page 5:

```
const limit = 50; // get 50 items 
const offset = 100;
```

and so on.

and that's how it looks like right now in my code where I get incorrect results.

```
const initialValue = 10;
const limit = initialValue * config.page;
const offset = initialValue * (config.page - 1);
```

What is the best method to achieve the desired results?

Comment: Your offset should not be calculated based on the `initialValue`.  Offset needs to be determined by the limit and the current paging index. And limit should not be fluctuating the way it is.  It should only be changed on user interaction.

Comment: yeah, I see but was interested if it possible with some method to get the results because I stuck here for several hours trying to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't described what "incorrect results" you're getting, but it looks like a fairly simple bug.

You mention:

> `limit` variable determines how many items need to load.

That's a common approach.  `limit` is basically the page size, saying "get me X items".  Normally `limit` would remain unchanged and only `offset` would be calculated.  However, your code continually increases the limit:

```
const limit = 10; // get 10 items
...
const limit = 20; // get 20 items
...
const limit = 30; // get 30 items 
...
const limit = 40; // get 40 items 
...
const limit = 50; // get 50 items
```

This is basically saying "I've scrolled through 10 items, now get the next 20.  I've scrolled through those, get another 30, 40, 50" – that's not a common paging approach.

Try keeping the limit at `10` and only changing the offset.  In that approach your code will (pseudo) say "give me the next 10 items after `offset`", which I suspect is your intention.

Comment: yes but the thing that `limit` should be increased with each page `limit`x`page`
and that's the problem. Do you think is there any way to make it work like that?

Comment: only if you want each next set to have more items than the previous set, but that's a very strange approach.  You might want to take a break for a bit to clear your mind.

Comment: No, Constantine, during pagination, the limit is not supposed to be changed except on user interaction to change the limit they wish to see. Your limit should remain constant, as STW pointed out, such that when you change the offset, you'll retrieve a different set of results.

Comment: It's an onside project with such an idea, I also found it's problematic especially when the page is high so maybe it's really better to change that behavior to the regular limit number.